# JPA and MongoDB persistance

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, relational-database, polyglot-persistance

I have an Apartment class which has some attributes and I am using JPA annotations to persist It, I also need to include images, videos and coordinates and I think MongoDB is best for that, Is there anyway I can use both database and still maintain integrity and consistency.
How would I refer the data when I call it,
How would it look like in the service functions and controllers?

I was thinking to use Long ID and use that to reference everything